# How to insert after a sibling element in d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js, charts

I want to insert a `foreign object` when people zoom in on a circle. I know there is a `Insert before` :

```
function zoom(d, i) {
     d3.select("g").insert("foreignObject",'#'+d.name) // insert after a circle in the group
          .attr("width",450)
          .attr("height",450) 
          .attr("id",'f_'+d.name)
          .append("xhtml:div")
          .html(content)

}
```

but the html content would be obscured by the clicked circle. Is there a `insert after a specific sibling` so that the foreignObject would be inserted after it?

Don't bother Robert Longson's answer. He just took something he read in the document without proving that works.

@ Code:

```
var w = 1280,
    h = 800,
    r = 720,
    x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, r]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, r]),
    node,
    root;

var pack = d3.layout.pack()
    .size([r, r])
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; })

var vis = d3.select("body").insert("svg:svg", "h2")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
  .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w - r) / 2 + "," + (h - r) / 2 + ")");

node = root = data;
  console.log(node)
  var nodes = pack.nodes(root);

  vis.selectAll("circle")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("svg:circle")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "parent" : "child"; })
  .attr("id",function(d){ return d.name; })
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
      .on("click", function(d) { return zoom(node == d ? root : d); });

  vis.selectAll("text")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("svg:text")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "parent" : "child"; })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("opacity", function(d) { return d.r > 20 ? 1 : 0; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  d3.select(window).on("click", function() { zoom(root); });


function zoom(d, i) {
  console.log(d)
  var k = r / d.r / 2;
  x.domain([d.x - d.r, d.x + d.r]);
  y.domain([d.y - d.r, d.y + d.r]);

  var t = vis.transition()
      .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750);

  t.selectAll("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
      .attr("r", function(d) { return k * d.r; });

  t.selectAll("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
      .style("opacity", function(d) { return k * d.r > 20 ? 1 : 0; });
  if(!d.children)
  {    
    if(!$('#f_'+d.name).length){ 
  d3.select("g").insert("foreignObject",'#'+d.name)
      .attr("width",450)
      .attr("height",450) 
      .attr("id",'f_'+d.name)
      .append("xhtml:div")
      .html('<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/60163c0083f4d2a54de2bb079a7211f8?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">')
    }
  }
  else
  {
     $("foreignObject").attr("opacity",0); 

  }    
  node = d;
  d3.event.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 21):

You can use css "element+element" selector ([direct adjacent combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#adjacent-d-combinators)).
Let's say you need to insert element "second" right after element "first":

```
d3.select('body')
    .insert('div', '#first + *')
    .attr('id', 'second');
```

Comment: I did not think this would work in the case when there is no element after the `#first` one, but it does work, because as the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#insert) explain, if the selector does not match any element the `insert` is treated as an `append`. So yeah, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [insert](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#insert) to insert the content before any other sibling element, the existing sibling element is the second argument to the insert method.

If you want to insert after element x, you'll need to create a selector that returns the element immediately after x.

If you want to insert after all existing siblings then use [append](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#append).

Between those two methods you can insert anywhere.

Comment: Use the second argument to insert to select the element after that sibling element.